# How do I use a point class, rational number class, and line class to Solve a system of 2 linear equations?

Tags: java, line, points, rational-number, linear-equation

I am fairly new to computer science and have been trying, unsuccessfully, to use a point class, a line class, and a Rational number class in order to solve a System of linear equations. The code for the System is old and I'm adapting it to work for the new one I'm making but I can't, for the life of me, debug/work-through one section of the code(the relates to the rest so if I can't do one I can't do all and the whole code doesn't work) at oneChosenFirst(). I'm not seeking the complete code but a very simplified explanation as to how to properly do this, thank you. Here is what i have in systems so far. the systems is based on user inputs too.

My Systems of Linear equations for slope and a y intercept:

```
public static void oneChosenFirst() {

    System.out.println("Enter values for Y intercept (0,#). ");
    double A = scn.nextDouble();
    double B = scn.nextDouble();
    Point Yint1 = new Point();
    System.out.println("Enter values for slope (Rise/Run). ");
    Line slope1 = new Line();
    }
```

Once again, many thanks, anything you think may help me on my journey through java is much appreciated.

Comment: You have to narrow down your problem. No one wants to look through all 600+ lines.

Comment: You really need to get rid of the excessive newlines

Comment: The code is better formatted now but it is still too much code. Please isolate where the problem is and ask for help with that particular segment of code.

Answer (score 0):

To solve a system of linear equations geometrically (as with your point and line classes), represent each equation as a line, and then the solution to the system is the point at which these lines intersect. If you are having difficulty with a particular step of this process, please say so and show what you've tried so far to accomplish that step.

Comment: @hell2the0 If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the unfilled checkmark below its rating :)